# #if statment to array of macros in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, macros

I set a target macros under `TARGETS -> Target's Name -> Build Settings -> Other Swift Flags` as `'Target#1'` and for the other target as `'Target#2'`. Now I have an `#if` statement that is checking which target is currently running and I want to do something different to each one of those targets, it goes like that:

```
#if Target#1 || Target#2
DoSomething()
#endif
```

or

```
#if Target#1
DoSomething()
#elseif Target#2
DoSomethingElse()
#endif
```

What I want to do is to make it a little bit easier to edit in one place instead of multiple locations inside my code, instead of adding to each `#if` statement the target's name, I just want to check if the macro is inside an array of macros. Something like that:

```
#define TARGETS_FOR_OPTION_1 [Target#1, Target#2, Target#3]
#define TARGETS_FOR_OPTION_2 [Target#4, Target#5, Target#6]

#if TARGETS_FOR_OPTION_1
DoSomething()
#elseif TARGETS_FOR_OPTION_2
DoSomethingElse()
#endif
```

Is that possible in Swift?

Comment: This is no different than centralizing the check for any other kind of condition (not necessarily a macro). You do it once, ina single place, to pick from one object out of a set of many. You put all your conditional behaviour in methods on those objects.  From then on, you just call the methods you need, and polymorphism will work in your favour to call the correct method implementation for your articulate circumstances.

Comment: The difference is if I want to exclude some files from compiling to the specific target. In your method I need to compile all files of the project in all targets, using Macro #if statement will allow me to exclude some files from compiling. Isn't that right?

Comment: Nope, you would only include files in the targets they belong to (using the sidebar on the right side of Xcode). The one file with the "switching logic" is the only one that would need macros to chop out the parts that rely on target-specific classes

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean, do the Macros #if statements inside a "switching-logic" file and make everyone call him. Great solution... :) Thanks! You can add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: IDK how to sum it up in a good answer, it's just basic polymorphism. But I'll summarize, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than scattering your conditional checks all over your code base, refactor using the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) technique.

1. Make a protocol that describes the operations that need to be done differently between different contexts
2. For each context you need to support, implement one conformance of the protocol
3. Make one centralized place that owns the "switching logic" which picks between the various objects. It will contain all your macros.
4. All other areas of your code base just use the switching logic to obtain an object that's appropriate for the context (without them needing to know what that means, exactly), whose methods they can just call.

Suppose the example was calling system APIs on Windows, macOS and Linux. You might have 3 conformances to your "SystemAPI" protocol, each of which calls system-specific logic. For this reason, you'll need to make sure that the windows file is only a member of your windows target, the macOS file is only a member of your macOS target, and so on.

Alternatively, you could have all files be members of all targets, but you'd need to wrap their contents in `#if`/`#endif` so that they're effectively empty for targets besides the one they're intended for.

Also, in the file that contains the switching logic, you'll need to use these conditionals to filter out references to the code that doesn't exist. E.g. the Linux target can't reference the Windows conformance (since it won't exist)